# Class 'Dotenv\Loader' not found laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel-5, environment-variables

I have both .env and .env.example file in root but still throwing error,Please help me

Answer (score 0):

This exception has nothing to do with .env file. Is simply says that your program can not find Dotenv\Loader class.

Try to run `composer update` then `composer dump` commands.